# get_type_hints raise NamError with local class

Tags: python-3.x, reflection, bug-reporting

I am using the python function `typing.get_type_hints()`. Unfortunately this function raise an error when I pass a local class that contains a reference to itself.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong ?
If indeed it's a bug where should I report it ?

```py
from typing import *

class Tata:
    parent: "Tata"

def example():
    class Toto:
        parent: "Toto"

    print(get_type_hints(Tata))
    print(get_type_hints(Toto))  # Raise NameError: name 'Toto' is not defined
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the class itself as the Type Hint, instead of strings (they end up becoming Forward References and it will lead to [namespace conflicts](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/508))

```py
from typing import get_type_hints

class Tata:
    parent: str = "Tata"

def example():
    class Toto:
        parent: Tata

    print(get_type_hints(Tata))
    print(get_type_hints(Toto))

example()
```